# Overlaying one image on another gives blue boxes instead of image - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure

I am trying to overlay one image on top of another in MATLAB.

I checked out [Superimpose two images in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18682875/superimpose-two-images-in-matlab)
for an answer. But the issue is that the overlayed images are being shown as blue boxes on the original image, instead of the actual image.

The incorrect output is shown here https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tH3Q.jpg.

The code I am using is

```
    a = 0.2;
    tform = affine2d([1 0 0; a 1 0; 0 0 1]);
    B = imwarp(z,tform, 'FillValues',255);
    B = ~B;
    figure; imshow(B);
    h = imagesc([X1 X2], [Y1 Y2], B);
    set(h, 'AlphaData', 1);
```

The normal `imshow(B)` shows me the correct image but the overlaying part is giving me the problem.

I have tried changing the value of `AlphaData` but that doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look to function [imshowpair](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imshowpair.html) with properties `Blend`

You can try this too :

```
figure;
h = imshow(FirstImage);
set(h,'AlphaData',0.2);

hold on;
imshow(SecondImage);    
hold off;
```

Comment: I saw that function, looked quite interesting.
But the thing is, I have multiple images being generated in a loop and they are being superimposed onto the original image.

How can I achieve that with `imshowpair`?

Comment: Like if you have 3 images to overlay?

Comment: Yeah, and the position for each new image needs to be set, as can be seen in my original code.

Comment: Maybe you can try to call multiple time imshowpair ? Like this : `figure;imshowpair(im,im2); I = getframe; figure;imshowpair(im3,I.cdata);`

Comment: Thing is, I don't know how many times I will need to call `imshowpair` since the loop is dynamic, based on input.
Also, how can I set the position of the superimposed image?

Comment: You'll need to provide a code sample and maybe a bit more information. Because Its starting to be a more specific problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55088/discussion-between-kanishka-ganguly-and-alexandre-bizeau).

Comment: This works fine but how can I set the position of `h` on the `FirstImage`?

Comment: Just catch the handle on first image instead of the second. I'll edit.